# When will an iOS application loads dark/light/any images from xcassets?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am in development of an iOS app which supports multiple themes. Some theme uses dark background colour and some uses light colour. Some of the default icons are not visible in dark/light backgrounds. I saw an option in xcassets to add images for different colour mode. My goal is to load an image from xcasset without using different icon name. eg: if I load an icon using ic-user, it should load appropriate image based on "SOME SETTINGS OR VALUE". Is this possible in iOS?, or is this feature only for macOS?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Automatically using different image asset appearances based on light/dark mode is only supported on macOS at this time.

It is rumoured that it will be added to iOS 13.

For the moment you will need to use code to load the required, individual, image based on your app's active theme.